# Bitwise & outputting numbers other than 1 and 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I have to '&' two 98 length bit messages, yet when I do the output contains numbers other than 1 and 0.  Could someone see where I am messing up:

```
print("The binaryCode of the input message is:", binaryCode)
print("The gsBinary is:", gsBinary)
print(len(gsBinary), len(binaryCode))

newStr = int(gsBinary) & int(binaryCode)
print("The result of anding the gsBinary & binaryCode was:", newStr)
```

This is the current output when run:

```
The binaryCode of the input message is: 11001111110010110010111000011110100100000110100011000011110011110100010000011001101110101110111011

The gsBinary is: 11001111110010110010111001011101110110110011000011110111111001111011101111001110010011001011110010

98 98

The result of anding the gsBinary & binaryCode was: 11001111110010110010110999119920984020956932636701193212439574622352446504985730534177701743362082
```

Why does the newStr print a string of length 98 with values other than 1 & 0 if the two input strings only contain one and zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to interpret the strings not as 10-base integers but as 2-base integers:

```
newinteger = int(gsBinary, 2) & int(binaryCode, 2)
```

Note the second argument to `int()`; `101` is interpreted as integer 5 and not 101 that way.

The output is not a string; it is another integer, so you need to convert that back to a string representation in binary:

```
newstr = format(newinteger, 'b')
```

Demo:

```
>>> binaryCode = '11001111110010110010111000011110100100000110100011000011110011110100010000011001101110101110111011'
>>> gsBinary = '11001111110010110010111001011101110110110011000011110111111001111011101111001110010011001011110010'
>>> newinteger = int(gsBinary, 2) & int(binaryCode, 2)
>>> format(newinteger, 'b')
'11001111110010110010111000011100100100000010000011000011110001110000000000001000000010001010110010'
```